# Is this strengthening of paracompactness known?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Consider a topological space $X$. What can be said about the following property?

- For any open cover $\mathcal U = \{ U_i \}_{ i \in I }$ of $X$,
  there exists an open refinement $\mathcal V = \{ V_j \}_{ j \in J }$ such that any set $V \in \mathcal V$ of the refinement intersects only finitely many other sets of $\mathcal V$.

This property is stronger than paracompactness, but is it weaker than compactness?

Does it hold on topological manifolds (which are paracompact and second-countable)?

Comment: Could you please highlight why is this not paracompactness? I can't see the difference (is it that you use the same index set $I$?).

Comment: Ok, that was a typo.

Comment: So what's the diference between this an paracompactness? Seems like a definition of paracompactness, isn't it?

Comment: The definition of paracompactness: for any open cover $\mathcal{U} = \{ U_i \}_{i \in I}$, there exists an open refinement $\mathcal{V} = \{V_j\}_{j \in J}$ that is locally finite, which means that for every $x \in X$, there exists a neighbourhood $O_x$ of $x$, such that $\{j: O_x \cap V_j \neq \emptyset \}$ is finite.

In this variation, the cover $\mathcal{V}$ is already a witness for its own local finiteness, in the sense that every element of the cover only intersects finitely many other elements of the cover.

Comment: My sense is that if we take a witnessing cover for local finiteness (the set of $O_x$) and take a common refinement with the cover $\mathcal{V}$, that we get a "self-witnessing" refinement. So the notion would be equivalent to paracompactness and not actually stronger.

Comment: @Henno: It’s what John Greever and some others called *hypocompactness*, and it’s definitely stronger: there are non-hypocompact metric spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This property has been called *hypocompactness*; it is strictly weaker than compactness and strictly stronger than paracompactness. The [Sorgenfrey line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology) is hypocompact but not compact: every open cover has a disjoint clopen refinement. Any [hedgehog space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedgehog_space) $X$ of uncountable spininess is an example of a paracompact space that is not hypocompact. $X$ is metrizable, so it’s paracompact. If $X$ has spininess $\kappa$, $p$ is the centre point of the hedgehog, the points at the ends of the spines are $q_\xi$ for $\xi<\kappa$, and the metric $d$ is as in the linked article, the open cover

$$\left\{B_d\left(p,\frac23\right)\right\}\cup\left\{B_d\left(q_\xi,\frac23\right):\xi<\kappa\right\}$$

has no open refinement that is star-finite at $p$.

**Added:** Henno reminds me that I forgot to answer the last question. Paracompact Lindelöf spaces are hypocompact, so separable metric spaces are hypocompact.

Comment: It seems that strongly paracompact spaces, where open covers have star-finite refinements, are hypocompact? That would imply a yes answer to the final question of the OP. Is hypocompact weaker than strong paracompactness?

Comment: @Henno: It's the same property. I learned it as hypocompactness as an undergraduate in the late $1960$s. I was pretty sure that it had a different name nowadays, but I couldn't remember what it was.

Comment: Strongly paracompact is what Engelking uses. So I know it under that name.

Comment: See the paper http://purl.pt/2253/2/P2.html for the definition of hypocompactness and the proof of the fact that a regular space is hypocompact iff every open cover has a $\sigma$-star-finite open refinement. Which trivially implies that $T_3$ Lindelöf spaces are hypocompact. The notion is quite old: due to Dowker 1947, according to that paper.

Comment: @Henno: Or John Greever, [‘On Some Generalized Compactness Properties’](https://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_pdf.php?issn=0034-5318&vol=4&iss=1&rank=3). He was working on this stuff when I was taking his classes.